# Cannot sign JWT in Angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt

I am attempting to sign a token in my Angular 8 app but I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` error for some reason.

```
// app.component.ts
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

var i = Math.random().toString()
var jti = i.substring(2, i.length)
var payload = {
  name: 'Name Here',
  email: 'Email_Here',
  iat: Math.round(Date.now()/1000),
  jti: jti
}
jwt.sign(payload, "de0cddc523drgegregregerge59cc80c01186fjy5jt045hyy6c5bef8")
```

Any idea why I'm seeing this?  I'm running node version 12.16.1 if that makes a difference.

Comment: token generation on client side ??

Comment: executed your code here on node.js and got JWT as result (added `var token=` in the last line). No error message or exception.